# How to preserve RS when using it for filtering a block in awk

Tags: awk

I have following data which is in form of blocks. Each block is separated by two kind of strings:

> 1. sep1
> 2. sep2

Following is the input data:

```
echo "$y"
sep1
abc
def
ghi
sep2
jkl
mno
sep1
pqr
sep2
stu
sep1
vwx
sep2
yz
sep1
```

Suppose I want to remove the block which contains `abc`: I used following command:

```
echo "$y" |awk -v RS='sep1|sep2' '!/abc/'


jkl
mno


pqr


stu


vwx


yz
```

It worked but removed the original seprator. How can I preserve it so the output would be like:

```
sep1

sep2
jkl
mno
sep1
pqr
sep2
stu
sep1
vwx
sep2
yz
sep1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another go. Using GNU awk and `RT`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="(sep1|sep2)\n"}/abc/{$0="\n"}{ORS=RT;print}' file
sep1
      # only 1 empty line like in the expected output
sep2
jkl
...
```

Documentation mentions about `RT`:

`RT` is set each time a record is read. It contains the input text that matched the text denoted by `RS`, the record separator. This variable is a gawk extension.

Comment: Hello James, thanks for replying. however, this will not help me as I need to remove entire block. By block I mean when I choose `abc` then `def` and `ghi` should also be removed. As these three falls into one block created by `sep1` and `sep2`

Comment: Right, my bad. Edited.

Comment: Also, you should adopt that `/sep[12]/` by @RomanPerekhrest (++) and modify it as: `RS="sep[12]\n"`.

Comment: @JamesBrown +1 and I highly doubt that the OPs 2 separators are literally named `sep1` and `sep2` so what you have with `sep1|sep2` is almost certainly the right approach though either one is easy to tweak if necessary. The OP is already using GNU awk for multi-char RS so also using RT as intended for this makes sense.

Comment: thanks , by any chance do you know any resource I could read about `RT` ?

Comment: I'd recommend the GNU awk documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Reading-Files especially 4.1.2 Record Splitting with gawk. Test it a couple of times and you've already mastered it!

Answer (score 2):

Through block processing (without `RS` pattern):

```
awk '/sep[12]/{ if (r) print (r !~ /abc/? r : ""); print $0; r=""; next }
     { r=(r? r ORS : "")$0 }' file
```

- `if (r) print (r !~ /abc/? r : "")` - print previous block contents if it exists and doesn't contain `abc`
- `r=(r? r ORS : "")$0` - accumulating each block lines

---

The output:

```
sep1    

sep2
jkl
mno
sep1
pqr
sep2
stu
sep1
vwx
sep2
yz
sep1
```